# When echoing boolean false, no text is printed

Tags: php, operator-keyword, operator-precedence

I found this question at http://www.phpinterviewquestions.com/php-interview-questions/operator-precedence/

Following operations are true or false? (Operator Precedence)

```
$one = true;
$two = null;
$a = isset($one) && isset($two);
$b = isset($one) and isset($two);

echo $a.'<br>';
echo $b;
```

I tried the above code. But only $b gets echoed as 1 (which is true). $a is not getting echoed. What could be the reason? I was expecting $a to be 0 (false).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not about precedence, it's about implicit type casting

Use `var_dump($a);` instead of `echo $a;`

`$a` actually is `false`, but being echo'ed `false` is casted to empty string.

Answer (score 1):

I think [@zerkms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251311/zerkms)'s answer (which is not wrong) is not the correct answer.

[@vaanipala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/853911/vaanipala) question (I think) is *why* `$b` is `true` and `$a` is `false` if both are generated by practically the same expression.

And yes, it's related to [PHP operator precedence](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).

`$a = isset($one) && isset($two);` can be rewritten as

```php
$a = (isset($one)) && (isset($two));
```

Nothing new or strange there, the parenthesis are practically redundant. But the `and` and `or` operators have **lesser precedence** of the assignment operator, so the line

```php
$b = isset($one) and isset($two);
```

is internally grouped like:

```php
($b = isset($one)) and (isset($two));
```

That first parenthesis has the value `true` (because `=` has greater precedence than `and`) which is assigned to `$b`. `isset($two)` is `false`, so that line at the end is processed as:

```
true and false
```

That operator result is `false`, but *it goes nowhere*. So... at the end `$a` is `false` and `$b` is `true`. *Quod erat demonstrandum* :-D